# If I add a WHERE 0 = 1 clause, does SQL Server know how to optimize?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

If I have a query like

```
SELECT * FROM vwComputationallyComplexQueryThatTakesALongTimeToRun WHERE 0 = 1
```

is SQL Server smart enough to see the `WHERE 0 = 1` and not actually execute the query in the view `vwComputationallyComplexQueryThatTakesALongTimeToRun`?

Comment: You could try it and look at the statistics (`set statistics io on;`) or look at the execution plan...

Comment: Yes, SQL Server is smart enough to identify a condition that evaluates to false. Since about v. 7

Answer (score 0):

YES, The SQL Server smart enough to see the WHERE 0 = 1 and not actually execute the query in the view.

***The Logical Processing Order of the SELECT statement***

is as following:

```
FROM

ON

JOIN

WHERE

GROUP BY

WITH CUBE or WITH ROLLUP

HAVING

SELECT

DISTINCT

ORDER BY

TOP
```

**Reference** :

[SELECT (Transact-SQL)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189499.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Yes. SQL Server will not execute query within the view. If where clause has contradictory statement(e.g. Where 0 = 1) then [constant scan](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188318(v=sql.105).aspx) operator will be applied. But SQL Server still uses [intent shared locks](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/61056/a-constant-scan-takes-either-0-seconds-or-2-3-minutes/61072) on underlying table.